# Grafana label_values regex to capture uri without query parameter

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I've created a repeating panel per API that my application calls, showing the http status returned.

The query that I could write for the variable so far is:

`label_values(http_client_requests_seconds_count, uri)`

And the selector is populated with URIs like:

```
/user/accounts
/user/contact_info
/account/details?accnr=1234
/account/details?accnr=5678
```

How should the query look like in order to omit the query parameter and get the result as:

```
/user/accounts
/user/contact_info
/account/details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *Regex:* `(.*?)(\?.*)?` (field located right under Query)

It will remove `?` and everything what follows it from your values. And also applies distinct after it.

You can't do this through query, mostly because even `label_values` is not part of query to Prometheus strictly speaking. `label_values` is Grafana's function for extraction of labels from Prometheus' (and alike) metrics.